# How can I return all nodes in an OrientDB graph that don't have particular descendants?

Tags: orientdb

For example, in the following tree structure:

```
root
  (name = a)
    (name = b)
      (name = c)
  (name = a)
    (name = x)
      ...
        (name = c)
  (name = a)        
    (name = c)
  (name = a)
    (name = e)
```

In which, there's only one type of edge in the graph called `HAS_CHILD`. The path from `root` to the first `c` node, for example, would be:

```
root-HAS_CHILD->a-HAS_CHILD->b-HAS_CHILD->c
```

I want to return all nodes named `a` that don't have a descendant named `c`. In this case, that would be the fourth node named `a`.

The XPath equivalent would be something similar to:

```
//*[not(.//*[contains(@name, 'c')])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a more efficient method, but this should work:

```
select from node where (name='a') and (@rid not in (select from (traverse in('has_child') from ( select from node where name='c') ) where name='a'))
```

[image]